# Returning a method with parameters to XSLT

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to call an external java function in my XSL code with Xalan processor XSLT 1.0
below is the method returning a value in Java.

```
public static String getBrand(String abc){

      return abc;
  }
```

í'm trying to get the value in XSLT using the below

```
<xsl:variable name="brand" select="xmlutil:getBrand(.)"/>

    <lastmod><xsl:value-of select="$brand"/></lastmod>
```

i'm still getting empty values. Can someone tell me how to pass a method with parameter to XSLT.
Returning a method without any parameter works fine,

Comment: Please show us a minimal but complete sample of XML input and XSLT code. `xmlutil:getBrand(@abc')` has a syntax error for instance.

Comment: The value I'm trying to fetch from XML is already in String abc and I'm able to print that in console. The problem is only when I try to call it in xslt. maybe I'm calling the in the wrong way(syntax error). I'm basically looking to know how to use a variable that is returned from Java method with parameter

Comment: Sorry that syntax error was a typo in the question. I've corrected now

Comment: Does it work if you replace `xmlutil:getBrand(.)` with `xmlutil:getBrand(string(.))`?